# Find Tables Without Clustered Index but with Primary Keys on a table

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is there an script to find Tables with no Clustered Indexes, but has Primary Keys on it for Sql server 2008 r2? Please let me know.

Comment: You can use metadata scheme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT
            so.name AS TableName,
            si.name AS IndexName,
            si.type_desc AS IndexType,
            si.is_primary_key
FROM
            sys.indexes si
            JOIN sys.tables so ON si.[object_id] = so.[object_id]
WHERE
            si.type IN (0, 2)
            AND si.is_primary_key=1
ORDER BY
            so.name
```

Comment: Or better yet: as of SQL Server **2005**, use the more specific `sys.tables` - saves you from having to always specify a `type = 'U'` for your tables.....

Comment: Much better! Also: I think it should be `si.type IN (0, 2)` - "0" is for "heap", "2" for other non-clustered indexes.

Comment: The si.name is not null clause actually eliminates any rows that have type = 0, just so you know :). Heaps don't have index names.

Answer (score 1):

```
select O.name
from sys.objects as O
  inner join sys.indexes as I1
    on O.object_id = I1.object_id
  inner join sys.indexes as I2
    on O.object_id = I2.object_id
where O.type = 'U' and         -- U = Table (user-defined)
      I1.type = 0 and          -- 0 = Heap
      I2.is_primary_key = 1
```

[sys.objects (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx)
[sys.indexes (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173760.aspx)